# Addition and Subtraction giving incorrect results

Tags: c++

I made a simple program to add and subtract the given numbers. Let's say the 2 numbers give were 5 and 5. It would print 5 + 5 = 10 and 5 - 5 = 0. Right now I'm not sure what's wrong. I might need a temporary variable, but something with the input isn't right. If you test the numbers with 5 and 5 it prints:

```
Addition / Subtraction Program
*------------------------------*

Press Enter to begin!
What is the number you'd like to add / sub to?5
5
What is the next number?5
55 + 5 = 105 - 5 = 0
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int num_1;
    int num_2;

    cout << "Addition / Subtraction Program" << endl << "*------------------------------*\n\nPress Enter to begin!";
    cin.get();

    cout << "What is the number you'd like to add / sub to?";

    cin >> num_1;

    cout << num_1 << endl << "What is the next number?";

    cin >> num_2;

    cout << num_2;

    cout << num_1 << " + " << num_2 << " = " << num_1 + num_2;

    cout << num_1 << " - " << num_2 << " = " << num_1 - num_2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should try stepping through a debugger to see what is printed when. You may also find that the `endl` used in the first `cout` statement could be used in other places to get the desired line feeds.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++11`) then learn to **use the debugger** (`gdb`).

Comment: Looks like you need to add some spaces or newlines when you print.  Your program is certainly writing `5 + 5 = 10` and `5 - 5 = 0`, but it's hard to read when it's all run together like that.

Answer (score 6):

The output is correct, it's just missing spaces.

After the user enters their number, you echo it back to them; without any whitespace. This "turns" 5 into 55, and 10 5 into 105.

The addition and subtraction are fine, you just need to format your output. End your `cout` lines with a `<< endl;` or `<< "\n";` to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The outputs are not incorrect. You only need to fix the formatting. In between the following two cout's, there is no clear demarcation:

```
cout << num_1 << " + " << num_2 << " = " << num_1 + num_2;//cout 1

cout << num_1 << " - " << num_2 << " = " << num_1 - num_2;//cout 2
```

Hence you get the output as:

```
 55 + 5 = 105 - 5 = 0
 |-cout 1 -||-cout 2-|
```

You can either use a newline (by `cout<<endl;` or `cout<<"\n";` between the two) or a space(`cout<<" ";`) to clearly demarcate between the two outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no problem with addition and subtraction. You didn't print the new line ('\n') character at the end of this line -

```
cout << num_1 << " + " << num_2 << " = " << num_1 + num_2;
```

It's good practice to add newline ('\n') character one `endl` manipulator at the end of each line.

In your current code, you have only formatting problem.